# AngularJS: Having trouble restructuring

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

Here is the current (Working) way i have my angular app.

**app.js**

```
    require('angular');
    require('angular-ui-router');

    var listStoresCtrl      = require('./controllers/store/listStoresCtrl');
    var createStoreCtrl     = require('./controllers/store/createStoreCtrl.js');
    var storeDetailsCtrl    = require('./controllers/store/storeDetailsCtrl.js');

    var listDepartmentsCtrl         = require('./controllers/dept/listDepartmentsCtrl');
    var createDepartmentCtrl        = require('./controllers/dept/createDepartmentCtrl.js');



    //-- init angular js
    var ngApp = angular.module('ngApp', ['ui.router'], function($interpolateProvider){
        //-- as the output conflicts with blade lets alter the defaults
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[['); 
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
    }).config(['$stateProvider','$logProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $logProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
        //-- enable logging
        $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);    
    }]);


    ngApp.controller('listStoresCtrl', ['$scope', 'Store', '$log', listStoresCtrl]);
    ngApp.controller('createStoreCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', 'Store', '$rootScope', '$timeout','ManagerService', createStoreCtrl]);
    ngApp.controller('storeDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', '$rootScope', 'Store', storeDetailsCtrl]);

    ngApp.controller('listDepartmentsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Department', '$log', listDepartmentsCtrl]);
    ngApp.controller('createDepartmentCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', 'Department', '$rootScope', '$timeout','ManagerService', createDepartmentCtrl]);

    //-- stick it all together and kick it off
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['ngApp']);
```

BUT i would like to restructure this so that my Store ctrls etc and Department ctrls are within their own module.

EG: **storeCtrls.js**

```
    angular.module('storeCtrls', [])
        .controller('listStoresCtrl', ['$scope', 'Store', '$log', listStoresCtrl])
        .controller('createStoreCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', 'Store', '$rootScope', '$timeout','ManagerService', createStoreCtrl])
        .controller('storeDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', '$rootScope', 'Store', storeDetailsCtrl]);
```

Then in the **app.js** file call them in like so.

```
    require('./controllers/storeCtrls');

    angular.module('ngApp', ['storeCtrls'], function($interpolateProvider){...}
```

But for some reason this does not work I am get getting an error of **Uncaught object**.

Bit of relevant history on this:

I am using **Gulp** and **Browserify** to do my JS.

My `listStoresCtrl` for example are using the

```
    module.exports = function(scope, Store, log){...}
```

method to return them.

**UPDATE**

i seem to have sorted the **Uncaught object**, as i was missing the ['ui.router'] with the call to

```
 angular.module('ngApp', ['storeCtrls']...
```

so it should be

```
 angular.module('ngApp', ['ui.router', 'storeCtrls']..
```

Now to get the rest to link up...

Comment: Have a look at this if you haven't already [seed app](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed)

Comment: thanks for reply its not a total angular app like that, and its seems its doing as i have tried the only diff is im using browserify etc and im not getting it to work at mo.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the main issue was i was not injecting some items that i simply removed and forgot to re-add.

I simply must of copied over this injection `['ui.router']` with the call to

```
   angular.module('ngApp', ['storeCtrls']...
```

where i should have been adding as well below:

```
   angular.module('ngApp', ['ui.router', 'storeCtrls']..
```

Now to get the rest to link up...